# Alternative IP to location database

Tags: geolocation, geoip

Is there any alternate database which compete with maxmind and ip2location city database?
I gets different results in these databases for an ip entry.
So which one should I trust.
`country, state, city, isp, latitude` for ip 117.201.195.13 in [maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/) database are

```
India   Kerala  Pathanamthitta  BSNL    9.2667, 76.7833
```

but in [ip2location](http://www.ip2location.com/) database, its

```
India   Kerala  Kottayam    BSNL    9.58333, 76.51667
```

in [ipaddressapi](http://www.ipaddressapi.com/) its

```
India   Kerala  Vennikulam  BSNL    9.4000 ,76.6667
```

what should i do?

Comment: you probably need to ask the ISP which city this IP should belong to, to confirm which IP database is more accurate.

Comment: but there are several isp's are there...
Its practically impossible to ask everyone for the details..
its just a sample case given above...
there are many other ip's with the same issue...

Comment: IP to geolocation databases are never 100% accurate, only approximate. There's also a certain time lag between the IP being allocated and the vendor updating their database. Maybe the IP did belong to both places at one time and has changed. Maybe it has already changed again. That's the inherent problem with IP geolocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally find commercial data Maxmind to be among the more accurate.

Other Options:

- [InfoSniper](http://www.infosniper.net/index.php?map_source=1&overview_map=1&lang=1&map_type=1&zoom_level=7&ip_address=117.201.195.13)
- [InfoChimps](http://www.infochimps.com/documentation/api-reference) (uses Digital Element data)

Nothing is perfectly accurate, your best bet is going to be to choose one strong provider and accept the inaccuracies. MaxMind is pretty responsive to updates, we've had several delays trying to get the data InfoChimps provides updated.

(Moderately relevant, I'm a co-founder at WonderProxy, so I've spent the past few years dealing with GeoIP data)